# Ejabberd - Only english characters and numbers for new registration

Tags: regex, character, ejabberd

How to disable the registration of a new username that contain non-English characters , numbers and -_. symbols ?
Version: ejabberd 14.07
Config file: ejabberd.yml
OS: Debian 8

Comment: ^[A-Za-z]+$ might do the trick if I understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `([a-zA-Z](?=\w+$|\d+)[^_|-|\d+])`

See Demo here https://regex101.com/r/uJ0vD4/1